# SQL Server GUID (from Active Directory) vs Int

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, guid, int

We migrated a lot of data from our old ordering system. This system stored the users initials in our "Orders" table for each order they created. Now that we have a view that looks at active directory I would like to update those initials with the active directory objectguid (or something that references the guid). This would allow us to change the users initials in active directory without having to worry about updating the "Orders" table records.

I've read that index performance is lackluster when using guids vs ints. One way to possibly solve this is have a table that maps guids to ints then store the int value in our orders table. Would this be a good idea? Any thoughts?

Comment: How is having a mapping table better than having the guid as a field in the table, but not being the cluster key?

Comment: My thought process is that the mapping table would have about 100 rows, would be quick to lookup the int, and if theres a performance benefit of using indexed ints over indexed uniqueidentifiers it would be worthwhile since our orders table have over 4 million rows. Please let me know if my way of thinking is totally off base :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that a *USER* entity already exists in your database design however, if it does not then I believe your solution will require it.

So assuming the *USER* entity exists, as you have described, you could place the UserID(int) on the *ORDERS* table, thereby relating all relevant *USER* details to an *ORDER*, rather than just initials (Note: Initials should arguably not be stored on the *ORDER* table but rather the *USER* or *USER_DETAILS* table, albeit not the focus of this discussion).

You can then add the GUID column to the USER table. I don’t think a separate lookup table is necessary.

Make sense?

Comment: I agree normally there would be an employees table. There was one in the old system and it really was horribly designed so we don't really use it now. I was hoping to just use our active directory view as the employees table and reference its objectGUID... but I guess this would be a big problem if for some reason the objectGUID in active directory changed

Comment: Not to confuse our "Customers" table with "Employees". We do have a customers table which is not the issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like you’re thinking along the right lines. You basically want to design a data model that supports the need to independently manage the database USERS from the Active Directory definitions, so that you may update each source independently without compromising the other.

Answer (score 4):

Index performance on GUIDs is in general no different from other indexes on a 16-byte field. Where the GUID's are deadly for performance is when you use them as **clustering key** on a SQL Server table.

The SQL Server table **is** the clustered key and is physically ordered by that key. Since the GUIDs are by nature totally random, this leads to massive index fragmentation very quickly, and thus requires a) constant feed and care and reorganization, but b) still suffers even if you reorganize every night. So really, the best practice would be to avoid GUIDs (even the new "sequential" GUIDs) for your clustering key.

For more background info and some excellent write-ups on why GUIDs make very poor clustered keys, see the blog of the "Queen of Indexing", Kimberly Tripp:

- [GUIDs as primary key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues....](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate....again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

Her insight is most valuable - read it, internalize it, follow it! You won't regret it.

Marc